# Do I need to carry my passport while travelling within the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, france, passports

If I have already entered the Schengen area, when am I required by law to carry my passport?

Basically do I need it when I

- Travel within the same city
- Change cities
- Board a flight or a train
- Cross borders

When I was in Europe I had two completely different incidents with me and I wonder which was legal and which strictly was not?

1. I was asked for my passport on the Metz, France train station while leaving for Luxembourg. Note: This was **NOT ON** the train but simply on the station because I was clearly a foreigner.
2. I was able to travel to Italy from Metz without my passport when I had accidentally forgotten it and had already boarded the train towards Italy. I was also able to come back and my passport was never asked for. I was traveling on a *EuRail Pass*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For EU citizens [it might not be strictly necessary to carry an ID when traveling around the Schengen area](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm) but you have to make several distinctions here. The fact that the police can and does check ID does not mean it's mandatory for everybody to have one on them. Conversely, the fact that there should be no systematic check at the border does not mean that it cannot be mandatory to carry ID (it's the case in the Netherlands for example and yet actual checks seem rare in my experience). Rules can also be different for locals, EU citizens and third-country nationals.

For example, regarding the first incident, French citizens are not even required to hold a national ID card at all but it's still perfectly legal for the police to do ID checks under certain conditions, even far away from the border ([more details here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/994/if-asked-for-id-in-france-by-the-police-as-an-eu-national-what-is-considered-va) or on [service-public.fr](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F1036.xhtml?&n=Justice&l=N14)). I think that even for third-country nationals (and certainly for French citizens), not having any means to prove your identity on you is not *per se* a punishable offense. The police might keep you for a few hours to ascertain who you are by other means or be generally unpleasant but you cannot be charged with anything just because you left your passport at home.

Furthermore it should be pointed out that racial profiling has long been a problem in France. I have no way to independently assess how widespread it really is but I heard many anecdotes and some organizations regularly complain about it. There are even a few official reports that acknowledged the problem and, back when he was still running for office, the current president promised a number of specific measures to deal with it. [The details are complex](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contr%C3%B4le_d'identit%C3%A9_en_France#La_pratique_des_contr.C3.B4les_d.27identit.C3.A9) but this gives you some idea of the context.

Now, under the Schengen agreement, France committed herself not to perform *systematic* checks at her borders. But anything else still depends on national law. For example, being part of the Schengen area does not mean that nobody can ever be asked for ID on French territory. Nor does it provide you with any practical recourse if you are victim of racial profiling or if you suspect French police is bending the rules. If France really is in breach of the Schengen agreement, this is something other EU member states and especially the EU Commission might deal with in several ways (potentially escalating to an infringement procedure in front of the EU court of justice) but that does not immediately help you in practice.

In fact, French law even specifically allows the police to ask people for ID at all times in border areas, on international trains and *[in a number of train stations including Metz](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contr%C3%B4le_d'identit%C3%A9_en_France#Le_contr.C3.B4le_d.27identit.C3.A9_dans_les_trains_transnationaux).* In 2011, the Commission looked at what France was doing and [issued a critical-sounding press-release](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_MEMO-11-538_en.htm?locale=en) but did not go further or challenge the law itself. [This guy](http://www.jonworth.eu/freemovement-net-mapping-breaches-of-schengen/) has been writing extensively about checks at the France-Italy border and elsewhere so it seems to be a relatively common occurrence.

All this also means that there are no EU or Schengen-wide rule that would definitively answer your question. It's certainly not mandatory to always carry ID everywhere but since police checks do happen, carrying your passport seems like a good idea in practice, especially as a non-EU citizen.

Answer (score 1):

> I was asked for my passport on the Metz, France train station while leaving for Luxembourg. Note: This was NOT ON the train but simply on the station because I was clearly a foreigner.

This was an anomaly, I would believe. I have moved around quite a bit in Europe. Always carry my passport with me, but not for this specific reason, and have never been asked to take it out in the past 5 years even when I have crossed borders within the Schengen region. ***Don't play the foreigner card(alibi).*** I am also a foreigner, and I have visited places where it is next to impossible to find a coloured person for miles in either direction.

Anyway when you applied for a Schengen visa, there should have been a printed note returned with your passport which says you have to carry your passport, proof of funds etc around always. Didn't you get one ?

Comment: I did get one I think. I remember being told but I don't understand why my EuRail pass was constantly checked (obviously because I was on a train) why wasn't my passport because how can the EuRail pass be validated without an ID proof? Especially when there's a high probability of me not being an EU citizen.

Comment: Also, I find it impractical to carry my passport and proof of funds and all that hefty stuff with me when all I want to do is get some lunch in Barcelona. :/ Wouldn't another ID work as well?

Comment: That is their country and their rules. Either you abide by it or don't go there. Sounds illogical, but not all of us are Gandhi, who will not rest until they change the system. For EUrail, they willn't mind as they have a traveller who does have a ticket. Whether stolen or not they don't care. In Switzerland I had the pass and put down my passport number as ID, but was never asked even once to furnish my passport.

Comment: The same happened to me as well. I guess you're correct. It is what it is. :/

Comment: I was traveling on an InterRail pass and my ID card was asked several times, to check the pass was mine and I was who I said I was.

Comment: "Don't play the foreigner card(alibi). I am also a foreigner, and I have visited places where it is next to impossible to find a coloured person for miles in either direction." I'm not sure what you are saying here. The context of whether you yourself are coloured or arevwhite would make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

By law most EU nations require all people to carry photo ID at all times and present it to police when requested.
There's usually a hefty fine for failure to be able to do so. And possibly a trip to a police station for fingerprinting and other means of trying to find out who you are.

While it's not common for police to be around, even when you need them, and even less common for them to ask for your ID (unless maybe you get caught up in a riot or major search operation, things like that), you can be asked at any time so best be prepared.
Mind that that doesn't have to be a passport, a European identity card or driver's license is usually enough (but might not be for non-EU citizens).

Comment: The police does not have the right to ask someone to identify him just for no reason. There has to be some reason, and they should be able to explain why your are asked to identify yourself.

Comment: @Bernhard I was asked to identify myself without any reason **AT ALL** two of my friends who were traveling with me were asked to do the same. We quietly obliged since we don't know any French either, but it did feel a little discriminatory.

Comment: Are they looking for a Proof of Identification or a Proof of Residence? i.e would my driving license from India work?

Comment: @AdityaSomani It sounds discrimanatory to me too. They should be able to explain why they asked for your ID (at least for the Netherlands, but cannot imagine it to be different for France). Their English is problematic of course, so they might have had some reason.

Comment: @Bernhard it depends, generally inside EU the police has the right to ask a valid ID (national ID, driving licence, passport) without explain the reason. Especially inside train stations are routine checks (I'm Italian and italian police asked me to identify myself 2 or 3 times while I was waiting a train)

Comment: @Adi  Driver's license should be sufficient for IDing.

Comment: @AdityaSomani if you are a non-EU national you need to carry with you the passport with the visa or a residence permit. Your driving license from India is valid to identify you, but not valid as proof you have a legal right to stay in EU (for tourism or as resident)

Comment: @Bernhard So Indian Driving License is okay as well I suppose? But the thing I find odd the most is that I was specifically asked to open my passport to the French Visa/Residence stamp page and they scanned it's authenticity with some eye-piece thing (probably UV light scanner).

Comment: @GuidoPreite I see. So passport it is! Thanks y'all! I did accept the answer based on the comments so please feel free to edit the answer to incorporate the comments in it as well.

Comment: @Bernhard nice in theory, but in practice they can make up an excuse if needed. And no, in the EU they need no reason, they've the right to ask for ID just to check whether you are in compliance with the law that requires you to carry ID.

Comment: @jwenting: There is no general EU directive giving the police the right to check a persons id card and neither any general rules obliging foreigners to carry an id or passport at all times. Some EU countries though, have such regulations in national law.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo maybe not at EU level, but at national level it exists in many countries. And even if there isn't, as I said they'll always find an excuse if they want one. And if you fail to comply, it's off to the police station, and in court it's your "I did nothing wrong" against their "we had our reasons" and you ALWAYS lose that.

Comment: @jwenting: Can you list these "many countries"?

Comment: -1 There is a little wiggle room in “most” but it's certainly not the case in several major countries (France, UK, Germany) so this answer is misleading.

Comment: "most EU nations"? Can you name one other than the Netherlands?

Comment: @Annoyed: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but France and Germany are basically at the opposite ends of the spectrum. In France everybody must carry identity documents; in Germany, you only need to be able to present them within 24 hours.

Comment: @Max: French citizens are not even obligated to possess identification documents. How can they be obligated to carry one?

Comment: My mistake, then. I was told this by French friends.

Comment: @Max As Tor-Einar Jarnbjo explained, it's not actually true for France (many believe so, perhaps because the police has greater latitude than elsewhere to check ID but see the link in my answer for more details on how it works exactly). I would also venture that the UK (no national ID card available at all) and the Netherlands (carrying ID mandatory at all times) are further away on each end of the spectrum than either France or Germany ;-)